# Interl fortran 2015 for construct mex file in matlab 2012a?

Tags: matlab, mex, intel-fortran

I want to call Fortran source code from Matlab use `mex` command.  However, I use Matlab 2012a while the fortran compiler is VS2013 + Intel Visual Fortran 2015(X64) in windows10(X64)，which is not supported by my Matlab version.

After some searching work, I find [a post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/156878-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2015-for-fortran) on Matlab User forum that seems a potential solution to my problem. It mentioned that I can "adjust certain .xml file to make it work".

But I don't quite understand how to adjust the xml file to my fortran compiler (it's already added to the environment path). Can someone explain the procedure in details or provide some other solution?  Many thanks

Comment: Hi, could you make more effort formatting your post. Writing Intel instead of Interl, using capital letters for Fortran, C++, VS , Windows and so on? Also spaces after the full stop after the end of a sentence would help. There should be no space before a comma. I also make typos, but it is good to read your post after you write it and correct them.

Comment: Of course, and appologize for my carelessness

Comment: In the days of old one could run a .dll from a MATLAB call. Does that no longer work?